# Firefox not showing up content, but no warnings on the output and the content is there. Works on other browsers, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, firefox

Please help!

I'm working on a re-do of a website, and they provided us with some pdfs. Thought jQuery would be the way to go. I have uninstalled firefox 4, reinstalled the previous version, removed the addons (Firebug), no errors there though but just thought it could be the issue or preventing the content from showing, etc.

Long story short, this code is working on Opera 11, MSIE 7 and 8, Google Chrome but not on Firefox for some reason, although the output has all the code there, it just visually not showing the content.

Thought as well that it could have been a conflict with jQuery, and made sure its not that neither. If you have had a similar problem in the past, or you have any ideas of what is causing this, please help! There is a deadline on this, and I have just ran out of ideas on what to do.

Thanks in advance,

J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firefox content isn't showing up because your `h1` that says "News Archive" is floating left, which is probably unnecessary.  Removing the float fixes the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the floatLeft class on the first h1 that contains the title "News Archive". As a side note, (yes I know you don't ask for layout advice but your site makes a css fairy cry) you are using excessive markup. You really do not need to have so many layers of tables. Not only will your users who have slower connections like your site more (less content to download and render), it will be easier to debug in the future.